# Returning value by select return

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have below mssql stored procedure. I want to retreive value either 0 or 1 depending on result insdie sp and return from sp. On my example when i debug it and when it reaches (i marked in query by  second arrow) comment point it doesn't go to `SELECT 0 / RETURN 0` lines but in window i can see "No column name" 0 - means seems to be fine as expected but when i debug with other input values and when it reaches (first arrow) comment then it also doesn't go to `SELECT 1 / RETURN 1` and morover no message like "No column name" 1 as i would expected. Why in debugger it breaks stored procedure on comment before reaches `SELECT/RETURN` statemts and why no result for `SELECT 1 / RETURN 1`. What i am doing wrong?

```
USE [temp]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsPhraseConnectedAlready]
    @PhraseId INT,
    @KatSubkatId INT,   
    @WordId INT,
    @SubsubkatId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    DECLARE @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories TABLE(Id INT)

    --spr. poziom 2-gi oraz wszystkie 3-cie
    IF @SubsubkatId IS NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId;


        Declare @id int;
        WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories)        
                BEGIN
                    Select Top 1 @id = Id From @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories;

                            BEGIN 
                                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_Html_WordCat_Phrase WHERE FK_Word_Categorie_ID=@id AND FK_Phrase_ID=@PhraseId)
                                    --INSERT SOMETHING
                                            --there is match existing already in db
                                        SELECT 1
                                        RETURN 1
                            END

                    Delete @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories Where Id = @Id;     
                END;

        --no match existing in db
        SELECT 0
        RETURN 0

        END


    --spr. ten konkretny poziom 3-ci oraz 2-gi
    ELSE
        BEGIN       
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID = @SubsubkatId;
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL;


        Declare @id2 int;
        WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories)        
                BEGIN
                    Select Top 1 @id2 = Id From @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories;

                            BEGIN 
                                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_Html_WordCat_Phrase WHERE FK_Word_Categorie_ID=@id2 AND FK_Phrase_ID=@PhraseId)
                                    --INSERT SOMETHING
                                            --there is match existing already in db<--------------------------------------------------------
                                    SELECT 1
                                    RETURN 1
                            END



                    Delete @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories Where Id = @id2;        
                END

        --no match existing in db<--------------------------------------------------------
        SELECT 0
        RETURN 0

        END
END
```

**To @Sean Lange:**

Note that when input value of @SubsubkatId is NULL then as in my sp this query has to be used:

```
INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId;
```

when there is somethnig (not null) then those queries has to be used (also in my sp):

```
INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID = @SubsubkatId;
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL;
```

I am not sure whether your simplified version matches that.

Comment: Why are you using loops here? This is doing nothing more than a single query with EXISTS or maybe even as simple as a join but taking the most complicated path to get there.

Comment: @SeanLange because there could be multoiple results and have to loop into each one. First which will find what needs should return value and stop sp.

Comment: But you are just checking for existence....looping here is a very painfully slow way to do this.

Comment: @SeanLange Could you then propose solution? Nevertheless i would like to understand why it behave like this.

Comment: But your code is basically the same thing I posted in my answer. If there is something missing then you need to explain what you are trying to do. Posting table definitions and sample data would be hugely helpful. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The reason your code is breaking out sooner than you think it should is because your IF statement has no begin/end. As such, the IF statement will execute ONLY the next line.

Comment: @SeanLange There is BEGIN and END before set non count..

Comment: @SeanLange Either i am blind or not sure whether do i need additional begin/end somwhere here?

Comment: IF EXISTS....but seriously this needs to be rewritten as a set based process instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: @SeanLange You mean to add additional BEGIN/END in two places where are "IF EXISTS" - just wrap two lines SELECT/RETURN by it am i right?

Comment: I am guessing that most likely that is what you want. Otherwise it will execute the first line when the row exists, else it will execute the second line. Just like in C# if you have an if statement with no {} it executes only one line.

Comment: @SeanLange One more thing why RETURN needs 1 or whatever else? Would it be fine to just say RETURN? I think Only SELECT needs number to retreive value howver i cannot find out why i put also value after RETURN. That is not needed right? Means only RETURN is enough. And from the other hand do i really need rest BEGI/END in my code bsides those after IF ?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the documentation. If you state RETURN with no value it will return 0. The RETURN statement is used to return a status of the execution as an integer. You could use it in your case since you are essentially returning a bit (0 or 1). But as I have said repeatedly, your process is horribly inefficient and needs a total rewrite.

Comment: @SeanLange Hmm does it mean that only RETURN x will be enough without select?

Comment: They don't do the same thing....look at the documentation. A select statement will return a result set(s) to the calling program. A return value is an output parameter limited to the int datatype. I don't know how you are using this but it seems redundant to do both. If you fixed the code to something like my answer this would all be water under bridge anyway because they code would be correct.

Comment: @SeanLange What i am doing is to get value to external application i wrote in VB.NET. I pass input values to this sp and then getting Scalar by ExecuteScalar method.

Comment: Right it is obvious it returns a single value. I give up. I have tried and tried to get you to see that doing this with loops is the wrong way to go but you won't share enough information so others can help. I hope at some point you are able to break away from the looping mentality but you don't seem to want to do that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want but pretty sure you can simplify your ENTIRE procedure to a single statement like this. There is absolutely no need for looping and making this so complicated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsPhraseConnectedAlready]
    @PhraseId INT,
    @KatSubkatId INT,   
    @WordId INT,
    @SubsubkatId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    select DoesItExist = convert(bit, count(*)) 
    from T_Html_Word_Categories c
    join T_Html_WordCat_Phrase wcp pm wcp.FK_Word_Categorie_ID = c.ID AND FK_Phrase_ID=@PhraseId
    WHERE c.FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId 
        And c.FK_Word_ID = @WordId
        And c.FK_Subsubkat_ID = isnull(@SubsubkatId, c.FK_Subsubkat_ID)

END
```

Comment: Look at my comment in main post at the bottom.